# General geodesics in Schwarzschild

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, symmetry, geodesics

In the general treatment of geodesics in the Schwarzschild metric symmetry is used to constrain the geodesics to a plane which is usually chosen to be equatorial.

Is there a way to generalize this, without restricting ourselves to the equatorial plane?

Comment: I would guess that the symmetries of the Schwarzschild metric are such that that is the most general case.

Comment: @JGBM sure, but I assume there is a way to solve Schwarzschild geodesics without using its symmetries. I am asking about this case

Comment: Yes. But why solving a system of 3 differential equations with 3 variables when you can solve a system of 2 differential equations with 2 variables and then perform a coordinate transformation to obtain all possible solutions? You can check page 2 of https://www.physics.usu.edu/Wheeler/GenRel2015/Notes/GRSchwarzschildGeodesics.pdf for the full system of equations.

Comment: Well, I am trying to describe the photon rings around the BH and restricting to the equatorial plane makes it a bit harder to generalize back to the entire photon ring.

Comment: I would think that, after having a trajectory, it isn't too difficult to perform rotations on the sphere to obtain any trajectory. But in your case, there might be more things at play than just the geodesics, no?

Comment: I haven't been able to do these rotations further in the calculation...

Comment: @JGBM Given that the ODEs nicely decouple, solving the 3 ODEs is actually much simpler then trying to rotate afterwards.

Comment: @Geigercounter I see. I don't think it will be significantly easier to solve the equations in full generality. But that is more a matter of taste.

Comment: @TimRias I would interpret the fact that ODEs decouple as a consequence of the symmetries.

Comment: @TimRias What's so hard about doing the rotations? Sure, it's a little messy doing it with traditional spherical trig, but it's straightforward if you convert from spherical coords to cartesian & use rotation matrices. Isn't it?

Comment: @PM2Ring it is mostly just very messy.

Comment: @JGBM In kerr in the absence of spherical symmetry they still decouple.

Comment: The trajectory of any geodesic in the Schwarzschild spacetime is automatically in an equatorial plane, because the position at the moment, the position at the next moment, and the origin are three points that form some equatorial plane.

Comment: @TimRias, that is still highly symmetric.